# CSS is there something like a "class subclass"?

Tags: html, css

I have 20 inputs in a page that are styled as buttons using the class property (that is, in the css I define borders, padding, width, etc).

But I want each one to have a different background color. In my current CSS I have 20 classes (one for each input) which are copies of all the style properties except for background-color.

It is working OK like this, but I feel somewhat uncomfortable repeting code. In there a very simple way to define most of the properties for all inputs (borders, padding, width...) and then specify the background-color, one for each input?

Comment: Post the code you have please.

Comment: Can you give us some example code?

Comment: you can simplay use a general button class and make a own class for each color. then apply both classes to each button

Comment: Style them via parent `#form_id inputs {/*general properties for all inputs*/}` or set the same class to each one input.

Comment: @j08691 I'm sorry, but this question does not need any code to answer it.

Comment: @Adjit thanks for your opinion but I'd like to see what the OP has done.

Comment: @j08691 understandable from a teaching standpoint - but the OP clearly stated what they had done. `I have 20 classes (one for each input) which are copies of all the style properties except for background-color`

Comment: As answered below, I had a very basic knowledge gap (id est, that you can apply several classes to a single element). I have no problem posting the code, but think that is not necessary any more, only 15 minutes after posting the question: you guys are great. Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="btn red" value="Red">
<input type="text" class="btn green" value="green">
<input type="text" class="btn blue" value="blue">
<input type="text" class="btn black" value="black">
<input type="text" class="btn orange" value="orange">
```

CSS

```
.btn{
    border:1px solid grey;
    width:50px;
    height:10px;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 10px;    
}
.red{
    background-color:red;
}

.green{
    background-color:green;
}

.blue{
    background-color:blue;
}
.black{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}

.orange{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avnaveen91/vw7mf9a7/1/)

Comment: As I answered below, I didn't know you can apply multiple classes to an element. A very basic knowledge gap on my side (I'm biologist really). Thanks a lot, and excuse me for being soooo newbie.

Comment: Thats ok :) and We get to learn new things every single day :)

Comment: You did not give an explanation why this works, but perhaps the answer is that you can apply multiple css classes to HTML elements and you start with your "base class" and add in more specification or "sub class" to the right of the class attribute value ? Plus though for working fiddle nice and easy to read and following along.

Answer (score 8):

You can use multiple classes on elements and use a common class on the elements for the shared styles and then a different class (or id) for the custom styles specific to that element.

e.g.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="input-class red" />
<input type="text" class="input-class green" />
```

**CSS**

```
.input-class {
    margin: 0;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

You could use a different selector to target all text inputs rather than having a common class aswell:

```
input[type="text"] { 
    margin: 0;
}
```

As well as the above, you can create more specific selectors like:

```
.input-class.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.input-class.green {
    background-color: green;
}

input[type="text"].red { 
    background-color: red;
}

input[type="text"].input-class.red { 
    background-color: red;
}
```

Which will only target elements that match those selectors, situations where this might be useful is when you might have a class with the same name elsewhere that you don't want to be affected.

For example you might have already:

```
.red {
    color: red
}
```

So you don't want an input with red text on a red background so you can chain the class selectors together to be more specific.

Comment: ups! I didn't know you can apply multiple classes to an element (I'm biologist really). Think that would do the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Like your "subclass":

```
.class {
    /* for <elem class="class"> only */
}
.class.subclass {
    /* for <elem class="class subclass"> only */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a very simple way to define most of the properties for all
>   inputs (borders, padding, width...) and then specify the
>   background-color, one for each input?

Firstly, define the styling for all inputs, e.g. (or use a shared class etc):

```
input{
   border:...
   padding:...
}
```

Then, if the inputs are all children of the same top level parent, you can isolate specific ones using the [**`:nth-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) selector:

```
input:nth-of-type(1){   
  background-color:red;
}
input:nth-of-type(2){   
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Alternatively, provide each with a relevant class designation

Comment: How is this any different from what he described that he's doing?

Comment: `In my current CSS I have 20 classes (one for each input) which are copies of *all the style properties* except for background-color.`

Comment: And you're proposing 20 versions of `input:nth-of-type(1)`, no?

Comment: The question is about removing the duplicate styling from each of the 20 rules into a shared rule, and not about collapsing the 20 rules themselves

Answer (score 0):

There is not in native CSS, but you have other ways of doing this at your disposal:

You can define a common class that holds all of the style that are common across the inputs:

```
.my-inputs {
  border 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

and then you can modify that as needed

```
.my-inputs.city  {
    width: 100px;
}
.my-inputs.state {
    width: 50px;
}
```

So that in your markup, you can do things like this:

```
<input type="text" class="my-inputs state">
```

Another way you can do this is to use a CSS preprocessor which does afford you the ability to do class inheritance.  Take a look at the documentation for LESS and SASS:

http://lesscss.org/

http://sass-lang.com/